# Link old envs to conda

Tags: anaconda, conda

We've just migrated from windows7 to windows10 and had a lot of conda environments associated with each their own experiment.

The envs all exist in, say, `F:\backup\<experiment_name>\conda\envs\` and as they were created with conda, conda had them registered. Now - with fresh installs of Anaconda3 we've lost the ease of access from conda as `conda info --envs` only returns:

```
D:\>conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
root                  *  D:\bin\anaconda3
```

What's the easiest way to get the old envs listed as if they were created with conda? There must be a register somewhere that I could update...?

Answer (score 2):

You can add the backup path to `envs_dirs` in your `.condarc` config file.
It can be done with:

```
conda config --append envs_dirs F:\backup\<experiment_name>\conda\envs\
```

Or just with a manual edit of the file (it's YAML)

```
envs_dirs:
  - D:\bin\anaconda3\envs
  - F:\backup\<experiment_name>\conda\envs\
```

See the [official doc](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html#specify-environment-directories-envs-dirs) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

In my Anaconda installation on Windows 7 there is a file `C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\.conda\environments.txt` which contains a plain-text list of the paths of all my environments.

If I create a renamed duplicate of one of these environment folders (say to `mynewenv`) and edit the new path into the `environments.txt` file, it appears in the output from `conda info --envs` and I can successfully (as far as I can tell from a quick test) activate the new environment with `activate mynewenv`.

That may be enough to sort you out, but if there's anything about the old environments that still isn't registered properly then you should be able to [export](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#sharing-an-environment) the environment contents to a .yml file and create a brand new copy by [specifying that file](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-from-an-environment-yml-file) to the `conda env create` command.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. So far I think exporting the old envs is the right way. It still seems like a workaround instead of just registering the envs. Conda must have a function for that somewhere. Forgive me for holiding out for a second answer.